# How to create a histogram for a dataframe with just 1 column and multiple rows (row values should be plot on x axis and column values on y axis)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am looking to plot histogram for the following dataframe (see below)

```
   |  missing_values
---------------
F1 | 123
F2 | 80
F3 | 0
.
.
F84| 20
```

with values represented as F1,F2,F3....F84 on x axis AND missing_Values represented on y axis
Note: There is no column name associated to F1,F2...F84 as you see

Could someone advise on how to create a histogram for this? IS there any manipulation i need to do before i can plot histogram. I am not able to figure out what is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(x=df.index.values, height=df.missing_values.values)
```

If you ever need to transform the index in a ordinary column, you can use `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If your index (the first column) is sorted you can use a bar chart:

```
df.plot.bar()
```

or

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mykola Zotko, I went with the solution by Edinho since i was looking to fetch the index names and put them on x axis, column - missing_values values corresponding to the index names on y axis..it did the trick for me